# How to import mixin into all serializer - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mixins

I am having n- number of serializers in my current app..

i want to add one more mixin in header like `ModelSerializer` into all serializer like,

```
class AdminSerializer(CustomMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
```

now i am applying manually.. is their a way to override to apply all together?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class that is using the mixin (give a proper name):

```
class MyCustomSerializer(CustomMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pass
```

And then subclass each of the serializer from `MyCustomSerializer`.

Comment: yes i did like this but forgot to use pass  it raise error... thanks